# Sitecore Powershell Extension installation fails

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have to environments test and prod with the same codebase and content installed, and I have installed SPE on the Test system all fine and dandy, but when I try to do it on our production environment i get the following error in the Log file.

```
ManagedPoolThread #16 13:03:50 ERROR Error installing items/core/sitecore/system/Dictionary/PowerShell/C/Context/{6B4E4627-40C7-464E-9FB0-54350FBD3850}/en/1/xml
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Cannot cache phrase for invariant language.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsFalse(Boolean condition, String message)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.CachePhrase(String key, String phrase, Language language, DictionaryDomain domain)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaved(String dictionaryKey, Item item, Boolean reloadDomainCache, Boolean saveToDisk)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaved(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.UpdateItemDefinition(Item targetItem, XmlVersionParser parser)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference, XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean& removeVersions)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)

ManagedPoolThread #16 13:03:53 ERROR Installation failed: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot cache phrase for invariant language.
   at Sitecore.Diagnostics.Assert.IsFalse(Boolean condition, String message)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.CachePhrase(String key, String phrase, Language language, DictionaryDomain domain)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaved(String dictionaryKey, Item item, Boolean reloadDomainCache, Boolean saveToDisk)
   at Sitecore.Globalization.ItemEventHandler.OnItemSaved(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args)
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent[TArgs](EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator)
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.ExecuteAndReturnResult[TArgs,TResult](String pipelineName, String pipelineDomain, Func`1 pipelineArgsCreator, Func`1 fallbackResult)
   at Sitecore.Data.Managers.PipelineBasedItemProvider.SaveItem(Item item)
   at Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.UpdateItemDefinition(Item targetItem, XmlVersionParser parser)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference, XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean& removeVersions)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry)
   at Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush()
   at Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context)
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.<Install>b__4()
   at Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Install.Dialogs.InstallPackage.InstallPackageForm.AsyncHelper.CatchExceptions(ThreadStart start)
```

And I can't seem to figure out what went wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

Delete the 
`/temp/dictionary.dat`
 file from your webroot and recycle the website.

See https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2015/01/30/cannot-cache-phrase-for-invariant-language-sitecore-8/

Comment: Thanks for the linky that seemed to make the install work :)

But now it fails when I try to invoke the ISE, should I make a new Question for that or ?

Comment: yes, make a new question,