# Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 6.4 fails to load due to XmlException Root element is missing

Tags: powershell-extensions

We are preparing to upgrade from Sitecore 9.3 PAAS. So, we are customizing Sitecore 10.3 PAAS. Our 10.3 Dev resource group is complete and works fine; but for some reason, the 10.3 QA resource group is blocking my attempt to install Sitecore Powershell Extensions v6.4:

- package: Sitecore.PowerShell.Extensions-6.4.zip
- source: https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SPE/6.4.0

I get a dozen or so `XmlException`s like this:

```
1152 22:35:45 ERROR Failed to load XML control: c:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore modules\Shell\PowerShell\PowerShellConsole.xml
Exception: System.Xml.XmlException
Message: Root element is missing.
Source: System.Xml
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlReader.MoveToContent()
at Sitecore.Web.UI.XmlControls.FolderControlSource.IsXmlControl(String controlFile)
```

FWIW, I have already tried:

- restarting App Service
- clearing out the contents of `c:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore modules\Shell\PowerShell\`
- copying contents of that folder from a working 10.3 env (Dev resource group)
- deleting /temp/dictionary.dat file from webroot and recycle the website (idea from
  [Sitecore Powershell Extension installation fails](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16913/sitecore-powershell-extension-installation-fails))

Comment: Is there a permission issue with the temp directory?

Comment: The \temp folder permissions look identical on the working and non-working App Service: `drwxr-xr-x 1 Unknown+User Unknown+Group     0 Feb 12 21:05 temp`. But, interestingly, the owner is different. Owner for work App Svc is `O:S-1-5-21-173198137-1712111466-166214340-501`; whereas the Owner for the one not working is `BUILTIN\Administrators`. 
...That seems like a PAAS setup error, right?